# Velocity integration with Jersey, ResourceTool does not initialize properly

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, velocity

I'm integrating Velocity with Jersey and I'm facing a problem with ResourceTool for i18n.

The integration is done as follow:

**web.xml** (striped, keeping with relevant parts):

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   <context-param>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>velocity-filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>velocity-filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>rest-servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest-servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>my.package.demo</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>rest-servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, my **tools.xml** (in WEB-INF folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                               
<tools>                                                                              
    <data type="boolean" key="STRUTS_TOOLS_AVAILABLE" value="false"/>                
    <toolbox scope="request">                                                        
        <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ResourceTool"                 
            bundles="my.package.demo.Resource" />                               
    </toolbox>                                                                       
</tools>
```

I have then created a basic **VelocityTemplateProcessor**

```
package my.package.demo;

import static com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolContext;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.view.ServletUtils;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.HttpContext;
import com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.template.ViewProcessor;

@Provider
public class VelocityTemplateProcessor implements ViewProcessor<Template> {

    private static Map<MediaType, String> fileExtension;

    static {
        fileExtension = new HashMap<>();
        fileExtension.put(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE, ".html.vm");
        fileExtension.put(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, ".json.vm");
        fileExtension.put(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE, ".xml.vm");
    }

    @Context
    private HttpContext httpContext;

    private final VelocityView velocityView;

    public VelocityTemplateProcessor(@Context final ServletContext servletContext) {
        velocityView = ServletUtils.getVelocityView(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Template resolve(final String name) {
        if (isNullOrEmpty(name)) {
            return null;
        }
        final MediaType mediaType = httpContext.getResponse().getMediaType();
        final String extension = fileExtension.get(mediaType);
        if (isNullOrEmpty(extension)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return velocityView.getTemplate(name + extension);
        } catch (final ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final Template t, final Viewable viewable, final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        final ToolContext context = velocityView.createContext();
        context.put("data", viewable.getModel());
        final Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);
        out.write(writer.toString().getBytes());
    }

}
```

This works well, except for the ResourceTool. It seems properly loaded with the requested configuration (at least, that's how it appears in the ToolContext), however, when I try to call the `$text.my.property` inside a template, it seems that it uses a ResourceTool with the default configuration (with bundle named "resources"), and then fail to find my key.
It works when I explicitly mention `$text.bundle('my.package.demo.Resource').my.property` but I would like to make it more transparent for the peoples that will manage the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I found it. I had to create the `ToolContext` using an `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. Both injected with `@Context`. Works like a charm now.